# PHP - echo an array within a session array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So I'm trying to use a foreach loop to echo out all the values of an array in my **$_SESSION** array as follows.

```
 <?php
      foreach($_SESSION['movie'] as $key => $value){
          echo "Movie: " . $key;
      }
      foreach($_SESSION['session'] as $key => $value){
          echo "Session: " . $key;
      }
?>
```

I'm pretty new to **PHP** so don't have much idea if I'm even on the right track.

This is the var_dump of the **$_SESSION** array.

```
array(1) { 
    ["cart"]=> array(2) { 
        ["ACWED-09"]=> array(3) { 
            ["movie"]=> string(2) "AC" 
            ["session"]=> string(6) "WED-09" 
            ["seats"]=> array(1) { ["SF"]=> int(7) }
        }   
        ["ACFRI-09"]=> array(3) { 
            ["movie"]=> string(2) "AC" 
            ["session"]=> string(6) "FRI-09" 
            ["seats"]=> array(1) { ["SF"]=> int(2) } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What's in the session array. Do a `var_dump`

Comment: why you use $key?

Comment: can you  show us whole session array so we can see what are values are in  session.

Comment: array(1) { ["cart"]=> array(2) { ["ACWED-09"]=> array(3) { ["movie"]=> string(2) "AC" ["session"]=> string(6) "WED-09" ["seats"]=> array(1) { ["SF"]=> int(7) } } ["ACFRI-09"]=> array(3) { ["movie"]=> string(2) "AC" ["session"]=> string(6) "FRI-09" ["seats"]=> array(1) { ["SF"]=> int(2) } } } }

Comment: You don't have `$_SESSION['movie']` there. You have `$_SESSION['cart']['ACWED-09']['movie']` and it contains the string `"AC"`, not an array.

Comment: How could I get it to run through each array in cart and out put the Movie, Session and Seats then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The movie is nested in the `$_SESSION['cart']` array. You need to do:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item) {
    echo "Key: $key<br>";
    if (isset($item['movie']) {
        echo "Movie: {$item['movie']}<br>";
    }
    if (isset($item['session']) {
        echo "Session: {$item['session']}<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: So that prints but I still get errors saying undefined index                                            
Key: WED-09
Movie: AC
Notice: Undefined index: session in /home/sh5/S3663675/public_html/wp/a3/showing.php on line 107 Session:
Key: ACWED-09
Notice: Undefined index: movie in /home/sh5/S3663675/public_html/wp/a3/showing.php on line 106 Movie:
Session: WED-09

Comment: Are there items in your cart that don't have a `movie` or `session`?

Comment: You can test whether those keys exist in the item with `isset()`.

Comment: Checked with that figured out I had accidentally split the movie array, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this..

```
foreach($_SESSION['movie'] as $key => $value) {
echo  'Movie ' . $value . '<br/>';
}
echo '<hr/>';
foreach($_SESSION['session'] as $key => $value) {
echo  'Session' . $value . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An array pairs values to keys, as stated [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array.php). Keys are the indexes in the array.

```
foreach($_SESSION['movie'] as $key => $value){
    echo "At the index " . $key . ", the movie is " . $value;
}
```

So you should go with `echo "Movie: " . $value;` if you want to write the value. The key isn't relevant here.

Note that you don't have to use the "$key => $value" pairing if you don't care about the indexes within your loop. This works too :

```
foreach($_SESSION['movie'] as $value){
    echo "Movie: " . $value;
}
```

You don't have access to the value's index in that case.

Comment: Trying this gave me this error. Notice: Undefined index: movie in /home/sh5/S3663675/public_html/wp/a3/showing.php on line 104 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/sh5/S3663675/public_html/wp/a3/showing.php on line 104

Comment: @Joshm102 If you're getting that error, it means you don't have a session variable named `movie`. Did you remember to put `session_start();` at the beginning of the script?

Comment: Just posted a var_dump and it says the $_SESSION['movie'] has a value in it

Answer (score 0):

```
  foreach($_SESSION['movie'] as $key => $value){
      echo "Movie: " .$key."=". $value;
  }
  foreach($_SESSION['session'] as $key => $value){
      echo "Session: " .$key."=". $value;
  }
```

Here is an example for associative array what is key and what is value

```
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");

foreach($age as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify things from the OP what the session array has before guessing

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';

foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item) {
    echo "Key: $key<br>";
    echo "Movie: {$item['movie']}<br>";
    echo "Session: {$item['session']}<br>";
}
```